# Getting ttf/otf font localised name

Tags: python, c, fonts

Is there anyway I can extract localised name from ttf/otf font file?

A solution in Python would be preferred, but I am fine with any language.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you give as an example the name of .ttf or .otf file that has this information?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page

http://wotsit.org/list.asp?al=T

Note there are several specifications for the file format of ttf files. Pick one.  You need to decide which one is relevant for you.   You will then have to devise a method (Ex in C with a struct) to read and extract what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), the Python Package Index, is a good place to look for Python tools. I found a package called [TTFQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TTFQuery/1.0.2), which from the description sounds like it would do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, TTFQuery and fontTool can't extract localised font name :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like font files may have multiple localised names.

Example with the fontconfig tools:

`$ fc-query -f '%{fullname} (%{fullnamelang}): %{file}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnBatang.ttf 
Un Batang,은 바탕 (en,ko): /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnBatang.ttf`

I can select the korean (`ko`) name using the order in `fullnamelang`:

`$ fc-query -f '%{fullname[1]}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnBatang.ttf 
은 바탕`